# C++ Chudnovsky Formula for Pi

Tags: c++, formula, pi

I am trying to make a C++ application calculate pi for me. I have tried to implement the Chudnovsky formula with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

long fac(long num) {
    if (num == 1)
        return 1;
    return fac(num - 1) * num;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double pi;
    for (long k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        pi += (pow(-1, k) * fac(6 * k) * (13591409 + (545140134 * k))) / (fac(3 * k) * pow(fac(k), 3) * pow(640320, 3 * k + 3/2));
    }
    pi *= 12;
    cout << 1 / pi << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The goal of this was to have the program output 10 iterations of the Chudnovsky formula. Instead, I got this:

```
call of overloaded `pow(int, long int&)' is ambiguous
```

Comment: What did you expect? What actually happened?

Comment: Side Note: The Chudnovsky formula converges fast enough where you really only need 1 or 2 terms to reach the full precision of a `double`.

Comment: @Mysticial: Seeing you comment on questions like this always makes me laugh (;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never initialize `pi`, so your code has undefined behaviour.

Your `fac` function does not correctly handle `0` (`fac(0)` should be `1`).

`3/2` evaluates to `1` (because it uses integer division, which truncates), and this makes your formula evaluate to the completely wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

You almost certainly want to do all the math on doubles, to avoid lot of time-killing conversions. You probably also want to use an iterative implementation of `fac` instead of a recursive one (not that recursion is going to be a *big* problem, but this is a prime example of when recursion should really be avoided because it gains you nothing). Of course you also need to initialize `pi` as others have already pointed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

double fac(double num) {
    double result = 1.0;
    for (double i=2.0; i<num; i++)
       result *= i;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double pi=0.0;
    for (double k = 0.0; k < 10.0; k++) {
        pi += (pow(-1.0,k) * fac(6.0 * k) * (13591409.0 + (545140134.0 * k))) 
            / (fac(3.0 * k) * pow(fac(k), 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * k + 3.0/2.0));
    }
    pi *= 12.0;
    cout << setprecision(15) << 1.0 / pi << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I get the wicked long decimal?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: See the `setprecision(15)`. Seemed kind of pointless to calculate it to that precision and then only print it out to 5.

Comment: I'm trying to make this program output all of pi that it calculates. This means that I need a long decimal. How do I get this?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: You could try changing from `double` to `long double`. Depending on the compiler you're using, that might get you around 20 digits of precision (or perhaps even more). Beyond that, you'll need to look into some sort of extended precision floating point package.

Answer (score 2):

pow(-1, k) is ineffective as it is a direct translation from math formula to the code.

Use this instead:

```
      (k%2==1?-1.0:1.0)*fac(...
```

Edit:

Also your fac code is far from optimal too.