# Calculating Pi number with Chudnovsky algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

So here is some C++ code for calculating Pi according to Chudnovsky algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int fact(int digit)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=digit; i>1; i--)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    long double pi = 0.0;
    int precision = 10;
    for ( int k=0; k<=precision; k++)
    {
        pi += ( pow(-1, k)*fact((6*k))*(13591409+545140134*k))/(fact(3*k)*pow(fact(k),3)*pow(640320, (3*k+1.5)));
    }
    pi = 1.0/(12*pi);
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(80)<<pi<<'\n'<<M_PI<<'\n';
}
```

The problem is that this code returns only 15 right digits of PI number, another part of it is garbage... when precision variable is set to 12 or bigger it returns -nan. Can anybody help me with it? TIA
EDIT: Ubuntu 12.10 x64, gcc 4.7.2

Comment: Use double literals where you need a double, not integer literals, e.g. `13591409+545140134*k` should really be `13591409.0+545140134.0*k`, otherwise you may get integer overflow.

Comment: Your factorial routine overflows very quickly.

Comment: thanx, I've fixed it, but nothing has changed...

Comment: You need to use an arbitrary precision floating point library. You also will need a way to create large integers or factorial will overflow. Bluntly, you are drastically underestimating the complexity involved in doing what you are trying to do. See [this article](http://beej.us/blog/data/pi-chudnovsky-gmp/) for an example of Chudnovsky implemented using GMP.

Comment: The problem is that doubles only *hold* 15 decimals digits of precision. 53 bits' worth. You can't get a quart into a pint pot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028313/c-chudnovsky-formula-for-pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028313/c-chudnovsky-formula-for-pi)

Answer (score 1):

Use double for fact() return type as well as "result" variable inside fact().